# how to pass multiple text box values in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="Website_list">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="John.Doe@foo.com">
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="John">
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var subscriber_details = {
email : 'John.Doe@foo.com',
name  : 'Website_List',
fname : 'John'
}

</script>
```

i want to pass the hidden value in Javascript variable in same manner "Subscriber_details" .

So what should i do?

Comment: where is the value attribute ?

Comment: i dont understand the question.. are you getting these values from the hidden inputs or are you assigning it from your script tag object to each hidden input?

Comment: I want to pass the value from hidden field to script....!!
but  i m not able to do so..!!!
I want to fetch the value in above manner in script tag\

Comment: I m trying to run an API so i want to pass the form value in the API so how should I do that?? & How to run that API?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var subscriber_details = {
   email : "'"+ document.getElementsByName("email").value +"'",
   name  : "'"+ document.getElementsByName("name").value +"'",
   fname : "'"+ document.getElementsByName("fname").value +"'"
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function(){
  var email = $("input[name='email']").val();
  var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
  var fname = $("input[name='fname']").val();
 var subscriber_details = {
 email : email,
   name  : name,
   fname : fname
};
  console.log(email);
  console.log(name);
  console.log(fname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign id and some value to hidden input feilds:

html Code

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="my@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="name"  id="name"  value="somename">
<input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fname" value="fname">
```

Then get it by id:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
  var subscriber_details = {
   email : email
   name  : name,
   fname : fname 
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var subscriber_details = {
   email : $('input[name="email"]').val().trim(),
   name  : $('input[name="name"]').val().trim(),
   fname : $('input[name="fname"]').val().trim()
}
</script>
```

(if you are using jQuery).  Sanjay posted a vanilla js version that would work.

Answer (score 0):

try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/emzhoqbu/)

html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="sample@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="Kavin">
<input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fname" value="smk">
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var em = $("#email").val();
     var name = $("#name").val();
    var fn = $("#fname").val();
alert(em);alert(name);alert(fn);
  });
```